# How can I align a div right under another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a drop-down menu in Jquery and it's working perfectly but I have only one problem with the positioning of the menu. I created the menu right after I learned about jquery animations and I'm still a beginner so I didn't follow any tutorials.

So I was wondering how can I put the menu right under the button?

```
<div id="nav" class="grid_5">
    <a href=""> ABOUT </a>
    <a id="products" href=""> PRODUCTS </a>
    <a href=""> HOME </a>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Cakes </a><br>
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Cupcakes </a><br>
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Fudges </a><br>
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Ice Creams </a><br>
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Hard Candies </a>
</div>
```

The menu is set under the button using an absolute position.

Here is how the site looks while full screen:
[image: Image on my computer full screen]

Here is how the site looks while windowed:
[image: Image on my computer windowed]

I would like to learn how to do this with JQuery/JScript or CSS.

Comment: providing the CSS that is currently creating that placement would help.

Comment: I'm sorry about that I forgot. But the question was answered anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having that problem because the menu is being position relative to the `body` so as the window width changes the position of the menu moves.  To solve this problem you want to place your link and menu in an element with `position: relative` on it.

This will then mean that you can absolute position your menu relative to the container its in.  So something like

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div id="nav" class="grid_5">
        <a href=""> ABOUT </a>
        <a id="products" href=""> PRODUCTS </a>
        <a href=""> HOME </a>
    </div>
    <!-- When you position this absolutely it will now be relative to the container -->
    <div id="menu">
        <a class="menuButton" href=""> Cakes </a><br>
        <a class="menuButton" href=""> Cupcakes </a><br>
        <a class="menuButton" href=""> Fudges </a><br>
        <a class="menuButton" href=""> Ice Creams </a><br>
        <a class="menuButton" href=""> Hard Candies </a>
    </div>
```

Obviously it's better not to use inline styles and instead apply a class to the container

Comment: thanks :) I applied the position to the container_12 div

Answer (score 0):

Wrap nav and menu div in a div and apply the position relative by which your menu div position would work accordingly:

```
<div class="relative">
<div id="nav" class="grid_5">
    <a href=""> ABOUT </a>
    <a id="products" href=""> PRODUCTS </a>
    <a href=""> HOME </a>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Cakes </a><br>
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Cupcakes </a><br>
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Fudges </a><br>
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Ice Creams </a><br>
    <a class="menuButton" href=""> Hard Candies </a>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.relative{
   position: relative;
}
```